# Stax in Java return ONLY some Values for Specific attribute

Tags: java, xml, parsing, stax

I want to be able to retrieve only the information of  with attribute UnitID=7854, so that the program be able to loop through the XML data inside that attribute only and grab only the information for that ITEM.

I have a XML called employee.xml like this:

```
<inventory>
    <item UnitID="1234" Record="0">
        <id>1234</id>
        <dealerid>455</dealerid>
        <stock_number>1600Xtreme</stock_number>

        <details>This is some additional details &nbsp; about the 
        product</details>

        <make>Nvidia</make>                       
    </item>
    <item UnitID="7854" Record="1">
        <id>7854</id>
        <dealerid>587</dealerid>
        <stock_number>12TMAX5500</stock_number>

        <details>This is some additional details &nbsp; about the 
        product</details>

        <make>Realtek</make> 
    </item>
</inventory>
```

I have this JAVA code so far

```
public class StaxParserTests {

        static int userInput = 7854;

         public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
                String fileName = "/Users/david/eclipse/workspace/StructData_Len/src/Test1/feedForTests.xml";
                //String fileName = "/Users/david/eclipse/workspace/StructData_Len/src/Test3/employee.xml";

                XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
                xmlInputFactory.setProperty(javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES, false);

                try {
                    XMLStreamReader xMLStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName));

                    while(xMLStreamReader.hasNext()){
                  /*e*/ 
                  int eventType = xMLStreamReader.getEventType();

                  switch(eventType){
                  case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
                      System.out.println("Start found: " + xMLStreamReader.getLocalName());




                          if(xMLStreamReader.getLocalName().equals("item")){
                              System.out.println("emplyoee found ! ");
                              long id = Integer.parseInt(xMLStreamReader.getAttributeValue(null, "UnitID"));
                                  if(id == userInput){
                                      System.out.println("we found attrib userInput : " + xMLStreamReader.getAttributeValue(0));

                                      final String idTag = "id";
                                      final String dealeridTag = "dealerid";

                                      xMLStreamReader.nextTag();

                                      while(xMLStreamReader.hasNext()){
                                      switch(xMLStreamReader.getLocalName()){
                                      case idTag:  
                                      System.out.println("id tag found. Value: " + xMLStreamReader.getElementText() );
                                      break;
                                      case dealeridTag:  
                                          System.out.println("dealerid tag found. Value: " + xMLStreamReader.getElementText() );
                                          break;
                                      }
                                      }
 }


                      }

                           break;


                  }
                  xMLStreamReader.next();

                    }


                    xMLStreamReader.close();
                }catch (FileNotFoundException | XMLStreamException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();


                       }
         }

    }
```

So the goal would be that the StreamReader could go through the TAGs of the item "7854" and if it finds for example , it stores the ElementText of it in a variable, to format and output later.

Please give me some guidance.. Thanks!

Comment: 7854 appeared twice one as text the other as attr val.. which one is used as your filtering critera

Comment: It would be the one as attribute that is inside this tag  <item UnitID="7854" Record="1"> .

Comment: is stax a requirement or you are open to some xpath capable libs? it would be so much easiler, I think <10 lines is possible.

Comment: Well, I tried with xpath and I had problems with compiling due to the existence of a &nbsp; character that you can see on the <details> tag text.  That is the only reason why I stoped using xpath, and moved to Stax adding this line, to avoid the &nbsp; problem:

{
xmlInputFactory.setProperty(javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES, false);
}

Comment: well that is an invalid xml entity... so it is not a well-formed xml

Comment: That I know, that's why I am trying to use Stax instead, because it overcomes that invalid xml entity. The XML I receive can't be modified because it has thousands of records, and that's how the XML provider(a big company)  send it to us. They wont change it just for us.

Comment: It is rather sad to hear that the producer of ill-formed xml documents won't correct its own mistake... I feel your pain

Comment: Yeah I know it is. But my situation is, in a different field, like asking big brands like Audi or Chevrolet to do that kind of correction.